# Do I have to allocate and free records when using TList<T> in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics, record

The question more or less says it all.  Given the following record structure:

```
type
    TPerson = record
        Name: string;
        Age: Integer;
    end;
    PPerson = ^TPerson;
    TPersonList = TList<TPerson>;
```

Is the following code valid?

```
procedure ReadPeople(DataSet: TDataSet; PersonList: TPersonList);
begin
    PersonList.Count := DataSet.RecordCount;
    if DataSet.RecordCount = 0 then
        Exit;

    DataSet.First;
    while not DataSet.Eof do begin
        PersonList[DataSet.RecNo].Name := DataSet.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
        PersonList[DataSet.RecNo].Age := DataSet.FieldByName('Age').AsInteger;
        DataSet.Next;
    end;
end;
```

Do I have to use `GetMem`/`FreeMem` to allocate and free records an instance of `TPersonList`, or am I free to directly access the `TPersonList` entries directly?  My gut says that the code should be valid, though I'm not sure if there's any wrinkles related to record initialization or finalization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code's fine.  When you use `Tlist<T>` with records, it treats them as value types, to be copied around. There's no need to allocate pointers for them.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!  Now I have to decide if records or classes would make more sense to use for my business objects.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: Why do you declare PPerson? Make sure that you do not accidentally try to deallocate the memory of a TRecord from your list to which you were pointing in a PPerson variable.

Comment: It's a bad old habit more than anything else.